# Google Drive API creates multiple same folders after 99 files added to the sub-folders

Tags: google-drive-api

I add the files to a sub folder up to 99 files, when add next file, can't fine this folder in the files list by its name or id. using google gdrive api.
The code used below.

```
var file_list = gDriveService.Files.List().Execute().Files;
var root_folder = gDriveService.Files.List().Execute().Files.Where(f => f.Name.Equals("Folder Name") && f.Trashed != true);
var root_folders = file_list.Where(f => f.Id.Equals("Folder ID") && !f.Trashed.GetValueOrDefault());
```

The problem is, when upload the files up to 99 files to this folder, then add next one, root_folder or root_folders does not include my folder by name or id._

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem is related to `pageSize`.

By default, simple calls to [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) only return a maximum of 100 files, as you can see in the referenced documentation:

> **pageSize**: The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (**Default: 100**)

If you want to retrieve more files, you have two options (not mutually exclusive):

- Provide the parameter `pageSize` in your request, and set it to a value higher than 100 (acceptable values are 1 to 1000).
- If the number of files to return exceeds the specified `pageSize`, a `nextPageToken` is retrieved in the response. You can use this `nextPageToken` in a successive API call to retrieve the following files (the "next page" of files), if you provide it in your following request, as the property `pageToken`.

#### Reference:

- [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)